# Listing the elements of an equivalence class

Tags: relations

Say you have `x = {1,2,3,4,5}, y ={2,5}`, and `c = {2,3}`
and the relation `R: ARB iff AUY = BUY`
then asked to list all the equivalence classes of C

I had put down `[2] and [3]`, with `[2] = {3}`, but I'm not too sure if this correct

Comment: Please try to use correct $\LaTeX$ syntax. Your current notation doesn't help you.

Comment: It is in the correct syntax

Comment: Can you clarify a bit. So you would say that $\{2,3,5\}$ is related to $\{2,3\}$ because they both have the same union with $\{2,5\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood "the equivalence class of $C$".

The equivalence class of $C$ is precisely the collection of sets $P$ such that $$P \cup Y = C \cup Y$$

Since $Y = \{ 2, 5\}$, that makes $C \cup Y = \{2,3,5\}$, so the equivalence class of $C$ is precisely every $P$ such that $$P \cup \{2,5 \} = \{2,3,5\}$$

Such a $P$ must contain the number $3$; then it may or may not contain any of the elements of $\{2, 5\}$.

So the equivalence class of $C$ is $$\{ \{3\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,5\}, \{2,3,5\}\}$$